# Core Data - fetch-response is unable to open the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios9

I'm getting a lot of these prints in my console while running my application from Xcode 6 in my iPhone 6 with iOS 9 beta 5:

> INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0000000B-BDBC-0000-000B-0000FB00000B/Library/Caches/my.app.package/fsCachedData/F00B00D0-00B0-00EA-000D-000A00000AEE. Errno: 1

I saw this question asking for a similiar doubt: [Core Data info & error in console at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031491/core-data-info-error-in-console-at-runtime)

But I'm looking for a better technical answer, or with some tip of how to debug Core Data in a better way. Some of my Core Data saves are handled by other libraries, so it's not easy as making fewer saves.

Comment: Giving the fact that you have a bunch of issues with CoreData on iOS beta, have you tried to delete app, restart device, clean and rebuild your app, reinstall iOS?

Comment: I tried all that besides reinstalling iOS, but I put my iPod in beta too and I'm also having the same issue. :(

Comment: Hi i am facing the same issue here. I found the cause for my case (but cant solve it) - it was the Google Admob ads. Disabling the ads make the message go away. Despite showing this message, the ads is still showing. So i am guessing the ad is trying to access a cookie of some sort but unable to? Unsure.

Comment: Check few places: `NSURL * modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourCoreDataName" withExtension:@"momd"];` when you create url for `managedObjectModel` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` in line `NSURL * storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourCoreDataName.sqlite"];` the names have to be simmilar to you Core Data Name mentioned in XCode.